# Hibernate 4.2 + Axis 1.4 + Apache Tomcat 7 + maven

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, tomcat

I am trying connect by RPC to my web-service (.jws), but it deploying with next error (error displayed when i copy axis libs to tomcat libs):

```
 Initial SessionFactory creation failed.java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: TRACE
сен 30, 2013 10:45:56 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [by.bsuir.nikitin.medicine.controller.Controller] in context with path [/Controller] threw exception [Servlet execution threw an exception] with root cause
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: TRACE
    at org.jboss.logging.Log4jLogger.translate(Log4jLogger.java:64)
    at org.jboss.logging.Log4jLogger.isEnabled(Log4jLogger.java:39)
    at org.jboss.logging.Logger.logv(Logger.java:1953)
    at org.hibernate.internal.CoreMessageLogger_$logger.tracev(CoreMessageLogger_$logger.java:448)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.EJB3DTDEntityResolver.resolveEntity(EJB3DTDEntityResolver.java:58)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.EntityResolverWrapper.resolveEntity(EntityResolverWrapper.java:110)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.resolveEntityAsPerStax(XMLEntityManager.java:973)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$DTDDriver.dispatch(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:1151)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$DTDDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:1049)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:962)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:607)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:116)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:489)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:835)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:764)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:123)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1210)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:568)
    at org.dom4j.io.SAXReader.read(SAXReader.java:465)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:2015)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:1935)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:1914)
    at by.bsuir.nikitin.medicine.util.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:19)
    at by.bsuir.nikitin.medicine.dao.AbstractDAO.<clinit>(AbstractDAO.java:10)
    at by.bsuir.nikitin.medicine.dao.UserDAO.getUser(UserDAO.java:57)
    at by.bsuir.nikitin.medicine.dao.logic.LoginLogic.getUser(LoginLogic.java:28)
    at by.bsuir.nikitin.medicine.action.command.LoginAction.execute(LoginAction.java:29)
    at by.bsuir.nikitin.medicine.controller.Controller.performTask(Controller.java:66)
    at by.bsuir.nikitin.medicine.controller.Controller.doPost(Controller.java:59)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:304)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:462)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:562)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:395)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:250)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:188)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:302)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Axis can work correctly with Hibernate (say how)?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a mismatch between the Log4j version and Hibernate version you are using. Try using the latest [Log4j 1.2.x](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/download.html). Also make sure you don't have more that one Log4j versions is your classpath.